# ListBox, DataView, And DataTable.RejectChanges()

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, ado.net, binding

I have a list box which is binded to a DataView.

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Categories}" DisplayMemberPath="Name"></ListBox>
```

where `Categories` is a property to class that inherits the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface:

```
public class EditCategoriesPresenter : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private DataTable _TableOfCategories;

    public DataView Categories { get { return _TableOfCategories.DefaultView; } }

    ...
}
```

While all data changes to the underlying `DataTable` (row inserts and deletes, column value changes) are reflected to list box automatically, when I do a `DataTable.RejectChanges()` row changes are reflected but not column value changes.

I can understand why this is happening (the `DataTable.RejectChanges` does not raise any notifications for column value changes) but still cannot find any easy solution to solve it.

I also add the `OnPropertyChanged("Categories")` after `DataTable.RejectChanges()` but still no luck.

Any ideas?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when i work with datatables i always use BindingListCollectionView for binding, cause wpf do this anyway implicitly. but now i can use the Refresh() method to refresh my ui binding.

```
public BindingListCollectionView Categories {get; private set;}

this.Categories = (BindingListCollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(this._TableOfCategories);

//after reject
this.Categories.Refresh()
```

nevertheless, what does your ListBox looks like (just the xaml you posted or some datatemplates too)? can you post a screenshot?

Comment: Thank you very much! It works! My list box is so simple as in my XAML. But why you mentioned that? Is there any problem with this solution if I will use data templates?

Comment: i just didnt use DisplayMemberPath="Name" with a listbox before, i always use DataTemplate. but its all fine :)

Comment: Most of the time I also use data templates but for this list box which is really simple, I think DisplayMemberPath is the easiest way :)